# mysql char_length returns incorrect results

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
 select number,char_length(number) from all_numbers where char_length(number)!=10 and number='7034420082';
```

results are:

```
 +-------------+---------------------+
 | number      | char_length(number) |
 +-------------+---------------------+
 | 7034420082  |                  11 | 
 +-------------+---------------------+
```

how is this possible? number is clearly 10 characters.  i have confirmed there is no white space on either side of the number.

```
 mysql> explain all_numbers;
 +--------------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
 | Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default    | Extra |
 +--------------------+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------+
 | number             | varchar(16) | NO   | PRI |            |       |.....
```

Comment: Can't confirm. `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(7034420082 AS CHAR(16)))` gives me `10` as intended. You also said "where number is not `7034420082`" so my guess is that you have **something** added to the end/beginning of it. White spacing/newlines/etc?

Comment: What does `SELECT HEX(number) FROM all_numbers WHERE char_length(number) != 10 AND number='7034420082'` output?

Comment: h2oooooo,  in a web app, that uses this db,  i did the following:  <?php echo ":" . $row['number'] . ":"?>   this showed :7034420082:  which tells me theres no white space...  the hex result is 3730333434323030383220

Comment: What will length() function give you? To rule out encoding issues

Comment: @bart2puck Then you were wrong - there's a space in the end. Check the last two characters: `20`. In decimal that'd be `32`, and in any [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see that it's a space. :)

Comment: length(number) gives me 11. also, when i do select * from all_numbers where number='7034420082';  i get a result.  if there was whitespace, it should return no results....

Comment: Likewise, `SELECT 'foo bar' = 'foo bar '` gives `1` so MySQL obviously ignores white space in this instance when checking for equality. (however `SELECT 'foo bar' = ' foo bar '` gives `0`, so it seems to ignore APPENDED white spaces)

Comment: used php and got strlen($result) which was 11,  got strlen(trim($result)) which was 10.  So yes, there is whitespace... Thank you.....

Comment: You could also simply use `CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(number))` in MySQL. Is there a reason you don't use an int?

Comment: these are phone numbers, so i add them as strings because I wont be doing any math on them.  is that a terrible way to design db tables?

Comment: @bart2puck Not nessesarily, but you might as well keep them as bigints to avoid this problem. When you use `VARCHAR` **each character** takes a byte. [When you use ints they take consideratly less](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) with `bigint` taking max 8 bytes (same as `VARCHAR(8)` would.). When you save things as chars, every single character is translated into an ASCII byte (which is why `7` becomes `37` in decimal form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that OP's string has a white space appended.

`SELECT 'foo bar' = 'foo bar '` in MySQL ignores trailing white spaces, which is why it still came up on OPs result.

You can check white spacing by using `SELECT HEX(column)` which in OP's case gave "`3730333434323030383220`". Every character gets translated to two bytes (hex representation for the ASCII value of the character which would be 0-255), and if we look at the end we can see a **20** in there, which is equal to "`32`" in decimal, aka. [a space character](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Solutions (in the order of "*what makes most sense*"):

- Change the datatype to `BIGINT` (which also only takes `8` bytes compared to 16). `UNSIGNED` would work the best here, and support phone numbers up to `18446744073709551615`
- Remove the white space: `UPDATE table SET number = TRIM(number)`
- Use `RTRIM` as well: `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(RTRIM(number))`
- Use `strlen(trim())` in PHP